# Can't see the code of my python script when I open the python file. What to do?

Tags: python, python-idle

I have a python script. When I try to open it using my python interpreter, instead of appearing the code, I can only see the screen that appears when the program is running and I don't have access to the code of the program anymore.

I think that happened after trying to open the program using pycharm...but when running the same script using iDLE, I see the user interface (below) and not the code.

Please, select your task:

1.SEPARATE PARATEXT

2.REMOVE PARATEXT

3.SEPARATE CHAPTERS

4.CONCATENATE WORDS

5.FREQUENCY LISTS

6.SPLIT TEXT INTO SENTENCES

7.ENTER TAG

8.CALCULATE SENTENCE LENGTH

9.CALCULATE ERROR PERCENTAGE

10.MERGE FILES

11.LEXICAL INFORMATION

12.AUTOMATIC PROCESSING

13.PROGRAM EXIT

Selection: 1

I want to open the file to modify the code. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: I don't know your OS but if you right click the file you may see "Edit with IDLE" or you can open IDLE on its own and go to File>Open. Or open it using any text editor.

Comment: You are opening it with your python interpreter instead of a text interpreter.

Comment: @Ivan, I open with python iDLE e then instead of opening the scrip, what appears is the screen that was supposed to appear only after running the script

Comment: You need to be exact about what you did.  If you right click and select 'Edit with IDLE', the file should open in the IDLE editor.  If you select 'Open with' and then IDLE, it may run the file and display its output.  (This might depend on you individual system.) The latter is what you describe as the result.